# ImportError: Relative Import with No Known Parent Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, importerror

when I run this

`from game import resources`

this occur

`ImportError: cannot import name 'resources' from 'game'`

[This is how my folders are arranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u02K.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)